# MS SQL: Transform delimeted string with key value pairs into table where keys are column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL table that has a message field containing a string with key value pairs in comma delimited format. Example:

| id | date | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-5-2021 | species=cat,color=black,says=meow |

I need to read the data from tables message field and insert it into a table where keys are column names.

Format of the strings:
`species=cat,color=black,says=meow`

And this should be transformed into table as follows:

| species | color | says |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | black | meow |

The order of key value pairs is not fixed in the message. Message can also contain additional keys that should be ignored.

How can I achieve this using MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_split()` and some string operations:

```
select t.*, ss.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when s.value like 'color=%'
                      then stuff(s.value, 1, 6, '')
                 end) as color,
             max(case when s.value like 'says=%'
                      then stuff(s.value, 1, 5, '')
                 end) as s             
      from string_split(t.message, ',') s
     ) ss
```

Answer (score 2):

It is so much easier to implement by using JSON.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

This way all the scenarios are taken in the account. I added them to the **DDL and sample data population** section in the T-SQL.

> The order of key value pairs is not fixed in the message. Message can
> also contain additional keys that should be ignored.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Date] DATE, Message VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('2021-05-01', 'species=cat,color=black,says=meow'),
('2021-05-11', 'species=dog,says=bark,comment=wow,color=white');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
       , '[{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Message
          , '=', '":"')
          , ',', '","') + '"}]' AS jsondata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT rs.ID, rs.Date, report.*
FROM rs
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata)
WITH 
(
    [species]  VARCHAR(10)   '$.species'
    , [color]  VARCHAR(10)   '$.color'
    , [says]   VARCHAR(30)   '$.says'
) AS report;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
| ID |    Date    | species | color | says |
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
|  1 | 2021-05-01 | cat     | black | meow |
|  2 | 2021-05-11 | dog     | white | bark |
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
```

Comment: I ***strongly*** agree that using bespoke encoding is a mistake, when notations such as json exist to make this ***much*** simpler and ***much*** more robust.  As an aside; you don't need to make the json in to an array, so no need for the `[` or `]`.  Also, you can make things a little more compact with `JSON_VALUE()`, depending on the context.  [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06ebf654ee783a4b4d0a5595b100f5dd)

Comment: @MatBailie, I concur. The `JSON_VALUE()` is another great way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE PN.ColumnName WHEN 'species' THEN PN.ColumnValue END) AS Species,
       MAX(CASE PN.ColumnName WHEN 'color' THEN PN.ColumnValue END) AS Color,
       MAX(CASE PN.ColumnName WHEN 'says' THEN PN.ColumnValue END) AS Says
FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(date,'20210511'),'species=cat,color=black,says=meow'))V(id,date,message)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.message,',') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(SS.[value],'=','.'),2),PARSENAME(REPLACE(SS.[value],'=','.'),1)))PN(ColumnName, ColumnValue);
```

*Hopefully* the reason you are doing this exercise is the normalise your design. If you aren't, I suggest you do.

Comment: Yes, I am doing just that. I appreciate the feedback.