# Concatenated string split

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Customer in SQL Server 2016 that has a text column with values

```
I=3;A=500;D=20210422
```

I would like to split the I=3,A=500 & D=20210422 into 3 columns in a new table or view.

Comment: What version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS SQL: Transform delimeted string with key value pairs into table where keys are column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485622/ms-sql-transform-delimeted-string-with-key-value-pairs-into-table-where-keys-ar)

Comment: I have ttried create a function String_Split I have tried this (select id, value from customer
, row_number() OVER(partition by  autoidx order by autoidx)) as n
cross apply
string_split(allocs, ';')) it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Presumably these are just sample values and will vary? If you don't need to guarantee any particular ordering of the columns a simple solution is to use `string_split` and a conditional `case expression` to aggregate into new columns:

```
with v as (
    select value, Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) rn
    from String_Split('I=3;A=500;D=20210422',';')
)
select
    Max(case when rn=1 then value end) Col1,
    Max(case when rn=2 then value end) Col2,
    Max(case when rn=3 then value end) Col3
from v
```

Comment: When I try the expression I get this error message "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Operand type clash: text is incompatible with tinyint" the column is datatype text on the customer table i have has the columns id,account,then the column alloc that stores the data I=3;A=500;D=20210422

Comment: @PC55 you will need to `convert(varchar(n), columnname)` from type `text`. `Text` is officially superceded by `varchar(max)` although you should always choose a suitable size for the data you are storing - specifying a `varchar` size unecessairly large can have unecessary performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t.*, s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when s.value like 'I=%' then stuff(s.value, 1, 2, '') end) as i,
             max(case when s.value like 'A=%' then stuff(s.value, 1, 2, '') end) as a,
             max(case when s.value like 'D=%' then stuff(s.value, 1, 2, '') end) as d            
      from string_split(t.col, ';') s
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea899d9a99649ebe0dc1b2212f1d09df) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: When I try the method I get this error Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of string_split function. the column is data type text customer table i have has the columns id,account,then the column alloc that stores the data I=3;A=500;D=20210422

Comment: @PC55 . . . `text` is deprecated and will be removed from SQL Server at some point.  You should fix the data to use `VARCHAR()` or `NVARCHAR()`.  In the meantime, you can convert the values.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DECLARE @userData TABLE(
    var1 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    var2 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    var3 varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

WITH CTE_Data
AS(
    SELECT 'I=3,A=500,D=20210422' AS [MyData]
)

,CTE_Detaildata
AS(
    SELECT 
        P.*
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            LEFT(v.[Value], 1) [ID],
            v.[Value] AS [Data]
        FROM CTE_Data AS d
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.[MyData], ',') AS v
    )AS D
    PIVOT(MIN(D.[Data]) FOR D.[ID] IN ([I],[A],[D])) AS P
)

INSERT INTO @userData(var1, var2, var3)
SELECT 
    d.[A],
    d.[D],
    d.[I]
FROM CTE_Detaildata AS d

SELECT * FROM @userData;
```